# it keeps displaying NaN

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the following HTML code to display a table:

```
<form id="Marks" action="/u0877654/Mobile/individualmarks.php" method="post">   

<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Marks Remaining</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$questionId?>_qnum" name="numQuestion" rowspan="1">1 <input type="hidden" name="q1_ans_org" class="q1_ans_org" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="q1_ans" class="q1_ans" value="5"></td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q1_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" class="individualtext" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" />
</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q1_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="1"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr class="questiontd">
<td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$questionId?>_qnum" name="numQuestion" rowspan="1">2 <input type="hidden" name="q2_ans_org" class="q2_ans_org" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="q2_ans" class="q2_ans" value="5"></td>
<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q2_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" class="individualtext" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" />
</td>
<td class="noofmarkstd q2_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="1"><strong>5</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitMarks" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" /></p>

</form>
```

Below is what the table looks like:

```
Question No.     Marks Per Answer          Marks Remaining
    1            (value=5 text input)         0
    2            (blank text input)           5
```

Now I have created validations for the table above using jquery. If a row contains any number except for 0 (either higher or lower) then it will display an alert stating:

**Higher than 0:**

```
You have errors on Question Number: 
Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 

• You Have NaN Marks Remaining
```

**Less than 0:**

```
You have errors on Question Number: 
Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 

• You Need To Remove NaN Marks
```

Another validation is that if the user has left a text input blank under "Marks Per Answer" column theni it should display this message below:

```
You have errors on Question Number: 

• You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
```

I have two problems though as you can see. First of all it does not display the number for which question number contains the error, it should display question number for the first question which contains an error.

The other problem is that it keeps displaying NaN. It should display how many marks need to be removed to make it 0 or added to make it 0.

How can the two problems above be fixed?

This is my jQuery code:

```
function validation() {

    var alertValidation = "";
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    $("[class*='q']").each(function (i) {
        var questions = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]").text());
        var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_ans_text]").text());
        var txtinput = $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val();
        _qid = questions;
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


        if (txtinput == '' || txtinput == null) {
            alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
        } else if (marks < '0') {

            alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) + " Marks";
        } else if (marks > '0') {

            alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks + " Marks Remaining";
        }

        if (alertValidation != "") {
            return false; //Stop the each loop 
        }

    });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have no class named q1_mark. It's q1_mark_0. Fix the definition of  `marks`, and use a javascript console to debug

Comment: @Jeff I changed the class to q1_mark and etc but still not working. Lemme just update my code give me 5 mins

Comment: @Jeff Ok I updated code so that I updated the html, the jquery and show  how the validation function is activated. Can you please see if I am activating the validation function correctly as well please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing Strings when you do `$("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").text() < '0'`, so try the != (Not Equal) operator versus the < (Less Than). Example:

```
 $("[class*='q'").each(function (i) {
            var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").text());
            _qid = $(".q" + i + "_ans_org").text();
            _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


            if (!this.value) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
            }

            if ($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").text() != '0') {
                alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) + " Marks";
            } else {
                alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks + " Marks Remaining";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }    
        });
```

Otherwise use your variable:

```
 $("[class*='q'").each(function (i) {
            var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").text());
            _qid = $(".q" + i + "_ans_org").text();
            _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


            if (!this.value) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
            }

            if (marks < 0) {
                alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) + " Marks";
            } else if (marks > 0) {
                alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks + " Marks Remaining";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }    
        });
```

Comment: I will get back to you on this

Comment: Ok you sorted out the NaN problem, it is just still not displaying the qustion number in the alert

Comment: Btw I added this variable ` var txtinput = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val()); `. I want to check for empty text inputs under "Marks Per Answer" column. But this code `if (txtinput == '') {`  doesn't seem to check it, how do I check for a empty text input value?

Comment: Use `if($(textSelector).val() == '' || $(textSelector).val() == null)` this might work better.

Comment: With blank textinput I changed to val() and tried to use selectors in if statement but this causes question number to be NaN with the empty text input message. If I remove that little validation, then the other validation where marks don't = 0, then that validation works perfectly, displaying question number, and showing right number of marks to be removed or added

Comment: I have updated html and jquery in my question to show what it currently looks like

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .val() to retrieve a value from an input:

```
_qid = $(".q" + i + "_ans_org").val();
_msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";
```

**EDIT:** What selector are you using? Class selectors are simply preceeded with a dot:

```
var marks = parseInt($(".q" + i + "_ans_text").text());
```

Comment: But if you look at html carefully, the question number and MArks Remaining are not in inputs.

Comment: this one is `<input type="hidden" name="q1_ans_org" class="q1_ans_org" value="5">`

Comment: Try the selector that I have edited into my answer for the marks variable

Comment: Ok it is just the question number that needs to be sorted now, Twisty managed to sort out the NaN problem

Comment: Btw I added this variable ` var txtinput = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val()); `. I want to check for empty text inputs under "Marks Per Answer" column. But this code `if (txtinput == '') {`  doesn't seem to check it, how do I check for a empty text input value?

Comment: The question problem is likely solved in my answer, did you try changing the .text() to .val()?

Comment: I worked out how to display question number, I added a class to question number and created a var question which is similar to the `var marks` variable except only difference is the class name and then `_qid = questions;`

Comment: With blank textinput I changed to val() and tried to use selectors in if statement but this causes question number to be NaN with the empty text input message. If I remove that little validation, then the other validation where marks don't = 0, then that validation works perfectly, displaying question number, and showing right number of marks to be removed or added

Comment: I have updated html and jquery in my question to show what it currently looks like